# How to obtain unique count of categorical variable based on another categorical variable?

Tags: pandas, python-3.x, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with `date` and `cat_1` variables among other variables. I want to get number of unique values of `cat_1`, per date. Here is an example: Below is a toy dataframe.

```
         date foo
0  2019-04-21   a
1  2019-04-21   b
2  2019-04-23   c
3  2019-05-01   c
4  2019-05-01   c
5  2019-04-23   a
```

I want to get is the following:

```
2019-04-21    2
2019-04-23    2
2019-05-01    1
```

I got it, but I think it is a bit convoluted. 
My code:

```
a.groupby(by='date')['foo'].apply(np.unique).apply(len)
```

Is there any other straightforward way to get the same answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try `nunique()`. That should do it. Here is a toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'two']})

print(df)
```

gives

```
     A      B
0  foo    one
1  bar    one
2  foo    two
3  bar  three
4  foo    two
5  bar    two
6  foo    one
7  foo    two
```

and

```
print(df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique())
```

then gives

```
A
bar    3
foo    2
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

For more details check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309729/count-unique-values-with-pandas-per-groups) on SO.